# Is there anyway to programatically discern which property code is executing within?

Tags: c#, reflection

I wish to call something similar to

```
public static void Foo()
{
    PropertyInfo prop = xxx;
}
```

from

```
public string Bar()
{
   get { return Foo(); }
}
```

I want prop to be the PropertyInfo for the calling property, I am at a loss as to what xxx would be.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: You want to call Foo with the PropertyInfo of Bar?

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want this? It is very odd for a method to inspect the call stack for where it was called from. There are even optimizations that may throw a spanner in your gears on this, if `Bar` is sufficiently simple, it will be inlined into code using it which means you will never see `Bar` on the callstack in `Foo`. Please elaborate, I'm hoping there is a better way to implement what you want done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property is in reality two methods: get_PropertyName and set_PropertyName. You can get these method names using the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class:

```
public string MethodName
{
  get { return new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name.Substring(4); }
}
```

The Substring call removed the get_ part of the method name so you get the property name only.

Comment: Thanks muchly, adapted this to my needs :)

Comment: Nice trick! But I am fairly sure that the special names assigned to the property accessor methods (e.g. `get_X` and `set_X`) are implementation-specific, meaning `Name.Substring(4)` is in fact not *guaranteed* to yield the expected result. _(Reference: CLI standard, partition IIA, section 17: "Defining events".)_

Comment: Good point! As long as the code is compiled in c# is should work as expected though. I don't think there are any cases where this would fail then.

Comment: In Release mode, the call to the propery might be inlined. You should add the MethodImpl attribute to prevent the inlining.

Answer (score 4):

```
public string Bar
{
    get { return Foo(GetType().GetProperty("Bar")); }
}
```

Comment: +1 you answered my question as I started out ... editted a little to convey my actual intent sorry